# Android: no such file or directory error reading xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-permissions, file-permissions, file-exists

I'm updating an old Android app that took an xml file, parsed it and stored data into a databse.
The error i get is 'no such file or directory'.

The basic fixes i tried are:
-Place the file in the sdcard
-Place the file in the main storage root
-Use a different file explorer
But the error persists.

On the programming level, i've scoured many forums and haven't found anything i might be doing wrong:
-Declaring write and read permission on external storage in the manifest file. (almost every one points to this but i have these 2 permissions declared since the original version)
-Checking and requesting permissions in the app, even though they're declared. (i've successfully added this bit, and tested it to be ok. Permission is granted and detected.)
-Using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file.getAbsolutePath() (among others), and checking if file exists with file.exists(), it always returns an error.
-Manually inputing the relative and/or absolute path, and then checking if file.exists()

In summary, the file exists, i can pick it, see it, but my app can't seem to check if it exists or read is contents to a String...

After trying everything i could think of, i'm completely out of ideas...
Maybe someone can point me in the correct direction...

I download an xml file viewer which doesn't even requests external storage and it can access the file without a problem, so the issue is definitely in my app.

Some bits of my code, for reference:

`// Pick the file
public void pickFile(View teste) {
    // Check permissions
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 69);
    } else {
        // Show file picker
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}`



`@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    int duratione = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 70:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!", duratione).show();
            } else {
                //not granted
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted!", duratione).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}`



`File file = new File(FilePath);

if (file.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(contexto, "EXISTE! :)", duratione).show();
    return;
} else {
    Toast.makeText(contexto, "Não existe... :( | "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+FilePath, duratione).show();
    return;
}`

Comment: `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with files, and `checkSelfPermission()` and `requestPermissions()` have nothing to do with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Where is `FilePath` coming from? What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: FilePath:

<code>

// Pick the file
public void pickFile(View teste) {
        // Show file picker
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

</code>

<code>

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();

</code>


I'm testing on Android 9

Comment: `String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();` -- that will not work on modern versions of Android.

Comment: Interestingly, it 'works' (by that, i mean, it does not throw an erro), and i get a relative path to the file, which i can output...
Do you know what should i use instead?

Comment: "and i get a relative path to the file" -- no, you do not. For example, there is no requirement that the user choose a file via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. "Do you know what should i use instead?" -- please see the duplicate questions, in the blue box at the top of the page.

Comment: Got it!
I can't get access to the file, only get a copy of it's content...
Here's the code:
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s;
while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
 sb.append(s);
}
String fileContent = sb.toString();


A copy of the file content gets stored in fileContent.


Thanks for pointing in the right direction!